# Special char in UIWebview and Highchart

Tags: javascript, ios, character-encoding, uiwebview, highcharts

I'm trying to integrate some charts in my app with `Highcharts`.

I've designed some webpage and display them in `UIWebViews`.
They may contain some special chars like accents(é,è,à,...) and also a '©' in the credits.

But all this special chars are replaced by squares in the tooltip, legend, and credits.
I know my chars are well given to my javascript function configuring the chart, because it works on other browsers (even on iOS safari) and labels of axis containing special chars are well displayed.

Any help appreciate.

Comment: Which encoding do you have? Because should be utf8

Comment: The webpage use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: How about file? its also endoded correctly?

Comment: Right! The .js file containing the function drawing the chart wasn't using UTF-8 encoding. Thanks

Comment: So at this moment works properly?

Comment: hi zbMax...what did you do to resolve it?...i'm experiencing the same thing...tnx.

Comment: Currently, my .js file containing the functions for creating charts is UTF-8 encoded. My php scrypt is WINDOWS-1252 encoded. To display the special chars, I use their html code if I can set the option `useHTML` (for example with tooltip), or their UTF-8 code (for credits : `text : '\u00A9 myCopyright'`)